# Efficient object storage in a file in Java

Tags: java, json, file, serialization, storage

I am writing a Spotify-like app for an assignment.I have a `Song` and a `Playlist` class and I have files where I would store the data. In the constructor of the `Spotify Server`, the files are supposed to be read and their data transformed into `Song` and `Playlist` objects, which the client would then be able to play.
For example, when the Server is run for the first time, the files are empty and there are no songs and playlists. An administrator/user adds several songs and playlists. They are stored in those files. The application is terminated. When the Server is run again, the songs and playlists that have been added in all previous sessions (and stored in files) are loaded and a user can play them.
The question is what technique should I use to store the object data in the most efficient way.
I have considered the following options:

1. A database - I haven't studied how to make one and that's not the idea of the assignment.
2. JSON - I know that JSON is an effective way to store and send information in the network. But here, I won't be sending the information across the network. The server will read it from its local hardware. If I use JSON, I will make use of the GSON library.
3. Serialization - I could do it the traditional way. Make `Song` and `Playlist` implement `Serializable` and store the information in the files.

    The structure of the classes is as follows:

```java
public class Song{
   private final UUID id;
   private final String artist;
   private final String name;
   private final int duration;
   private int timesListenedTo = 0;
   private final Path filePath; // a non-changing path to the .wav audio file of the song
}
```

```java
public class Playlist{
   private List<Song> songs; // I could replace this with a List<String> or List<UUID> if considered more efficient
   private final String name;
}
```

What is the most resource-efficient approach for my task? My priorities in order are:

1. Minimal CPU usage
2. Minimal memory usage
3. Code complexity (the least important)

Comment: May I suggest that more important is code maintainability and readability.

Comment: A database would be by _far_ the best approach as what you’re building is a *relational schema*. A file - be it JSON or any other format will require you to read everything into memory and write everything out again - this won’t scale. Further, it will require you to build in-memory indexes of everything you might want to search - and partial string matches are expensive and tricky. In the end, you’ll have a homebrew in memory database, which will be guaranteed to be worse than an existing product. A good learning experience perhaps though…

Comment: @ScaryWombat I am just starting learning Software Engineering, so it's very probable that my priorities are messed-up. If I take your note into consideration, both Serialization and JSON seem equally easy to implement and maintain as a code. Am I right?

Comment: The big advantage of JSON is that it is _human readable_ - don’t underestimate this when it comes to building and debugging; especially as a didactic exercise. (Also Java serialisation is slow, bloated, and a major security issue - in fact modern JSON libraries are significantly faster)

Comment: @BoristheSpider I absolutely agree with you. In fact, that's exactly what's happening. I need to implement searching and for this I have to build a Map of the keywords, which would serve as an index. It's a mess, I know. But I am definitely not meant to use a database. It's about exercising reading and writing files in Java.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Indeed. It could be argued that in a real-world scenario, the data would also have to be sent across the network, perhaps even obtained from a second server. If I use JSON, the project would be so much easier to upgrade and modify in the future. I guess I've almost made my choice.

Comment: Unless your project requirements state that efficiency is an important consideration ... it isn't.  The first lesson of Engineering is "time is money".  Don't waste your time on things that are not important.  That includes optimizing for performance what that is not necessary.  (You have your priorities backwards!)

Comment: Human readability is not really important for network communication - in fact in a real world scenario I would hope to see a strong schema’d binary format (such as Avro, Proto etc) over an efficient pipelined two way transport (such as gRPC). The prevalence of JSON/REST for public APIs is monthly due to simplicity of implementation.

Comment: @StephenC I've already done homeworks, where I was criticized for inefficient data structures, so efficiency IS a concern. But not big enough to require me to learn how to connect to a database from scratch. Especially because I also have a deadline.

Comment: There is a difference between using the correct data structure for a particular algorithm - this is designed to teach you the difference between, e.g. a hashtable and an array - and performance optimisation around on disk formats. The latter being likely not the point of the exercise … unless the exercise says otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can [Perst](https://www.mcobject.com/perst/) give a try.

> Perst is McObject’s open source, dual license, object-oriented embedded database system (ODBMS). It is available in one edition developed as an all-Java embedded database, and another implemented in C# (for Microsoft .NET Framework applications).  Perst gives developers the ability to store, sort and retrieve objects in their applications with maximum speed and with low memory and storage overhead, while leveraging the object-oriented paradigm of Java and C#.

Answer (score -2):

you can convert the data object to bytes array and write it to a file,but if you think the java native api have a little slow ,you can try protobuf,wish you can get your way

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).